# unique=True gives already exist! Even if interchanging the values of two objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

To display objects (members) in particular order, I have made a field, `order`:

```
order = models.IntegerField(unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
```

so that I can do an `.order_by('order')` to get the required order.

In Django Admin, the table has only two objects with `order` 0,1. If I want to interchange it by 1,0 I get an error:

> About us with this Order already exists

[image]

For ease of using Django admin, is there a better method to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `unique=True` and add a custom action to reorder objects. In this form, Django admin applies each object in a separate transaction and it causes this error. You may override the update function of your admin class and do all changes in a bulk-update transaction like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update). But I don't recommend it. Because you may make a mistake in the future and want to edit other fields and this line makes a bug.